# jQuery dataTables not being populated when using javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable script as shown below

```
$('#genericTable').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "resources/json/apps.json",
        "sPaginationType"   : "full_numbers",
        "bJQueryUI"         : true,
        "bRetrieve"         : true,
        "bPaginate"         : true,
        "bSort"             : true,
        "aaSorting"  : [[ 3, "desc" ]],
        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
            $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html( '<a href="' + aData[3] +'" >'  +
                    aData[0] + '</a>');
        }
    }).columnFilter({ sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
        aoColumns: [ null,
                     { type: "text" },
                     null
                   ]
    });
```

when i put this code in ready function, table is populated perfectly, but when i put this code in some javascript function and calling this function with onClick, table is not getting populated.

Does anyone know the solution for this?

Comment: What do you get when you try to access `resources/json/apps.json` via browser or `Net` panel of the browser?

Comment: it is simply displaying json file.

Comment: Can you post the contents? Also try removing the callback functions and display...